# Props to set styled components background image using in React 17

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, background-image, styled-components

I am following a tutorial:

My home:

```
function LandingPage (){
    return(   
<Container>
    <Section>
        title='Top Model'
        desc='My Description'
        leftBtn='Buy'
        rightBtn='Add to Cart'
        bgImg='car.jpg'
    </Section>
</Container>
    )
}
export default LandingPage;

const Container  = styled.div`
height: 100vh;`
```

My Section:

```
function Section ({title, desc, leftBtn, rightBtn, bgImg}){
return (
<Wrap bg={bgImg}></Wrap>
    )
}
export default Section;
const Wrap = styled.div`
background-image: ${props => `url("/images/${props.bg}")`};
`
```

It's working in Video but not for me, When I inspect my elements I see background image as:

**background-image: url(/images/undefined);**

Note: I am new to react and using react 17.

Edited: I've checked all props i.e., title are not passing to Section

Comment: Your Section code looks kind of funny.  The `export default Section` should be the last code in the file.  move the `const wrap...` code directly under your `function...` line.

Comment: Moved export at the end but wrapping styling in functions makes code slow as per react's documentation

Comment: If you want access to the props, you need to have that inside your function.

Comment: Also, you are not taking in props or bg in your section signature.

Comment: Understood what you are saying but that is not necessary. Check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUeS9Wsj6dk React don't restrict my syntax as we've passed prop to Wrap style

Comment: Aw yes, you're right, i missed that.  Looks like taha found the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modify it like that

```
<Section
    title='Top Model'
    desc='My Description'
    leftBtn='Buy'
    rightBtn='Add to Cart'
    bgImg='car.jpg'
>
</Section>
```

that should work

Comment: Thanks a lot @taha. This was my first day in react and this corrected my way of passing data.